# Sodium by electrolysis through glass

Tags: metal, electrolysis, reference-request, equipment

In his 1926 thesis Robert Cady Burts [describes the production of sodium by electrolysis of sodium nitrate through glass](http://thesis.library.caltech.edu/4369/1/Burt_rc_1926.pdf).

I can't find much else on this method. Are there any modern descriptions of the experiment? Videos maybe?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 3):

See Shakashiri's chemical demonstrations. He carefully outlines the steps. As I recall it requires taking sodium nitrate into a molten state and applying a current. The elemental sodium is precipitated on the inside surface of an incandescent bulb.